# sklearn PCA returns components arrays close to zero

Tags: image, numpy, scikit-learn, pca

I am trying to use sklearn's decomposition.PCA function:

The input is 100 4096x4096x3 (RGB) human face images(in numpy array form(uint8),RGB,[0,255]range) which are read by cv2

I converted them to [1,4096x4096x3] 2d shape, like:

[255. 128. 128. ... 255. 128. 128.]

Then I put all these arrays into sklearn's PCA() with n_components=20 in order to find 20 main features.

Computation finished successfully, but all the components in PCA.components_ are very similar and are close to an array of zeros.

Here are all my trouble shooting:

1.The input images matrix have about 24% entries that have a difference >10 (in [0,255]scale) when compared with another input image.

The pca.mean_ is very normal: it is an array looks like the inputs:

[255. 128. 128. ... 255. 128. 128.]

and I can successfully reconstruct a human face image with it

However, I find that all the components are arrays consists of floats very close to 0, like:

[[ 1.4016776e-08  4.3943277e-08  2.7873748e-08]

[ 4.1034184e-08 -1.2753417e-08  6.2264380e-09]

[-6.7606822e-09  4.9416444e-09  5.4486654e-10]

...

[-0.0000000e+00 -0.0000000e+00 -0.0000000e+00]

[-0.0000000e+00 -0.0000000e+00 -0.0000000e+00]

[-0.0000000e+00 -0.0000000e+00 -0.0000000e+00]]

actually, None of them>1.

2.I tired use parameters like:

```
pca=PCA(n_components=20,svd_solver="randomized", whiten=True)
```

But the result turned out to be the same. Still very similar components.

Why is this the case and how to fix it, Thanks for any ideas!

Code:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os

folder_path = "./normal"
input=[]
for i in range(1, 101):
    if i%10 == 0: print("loading",i,"th image")
    if i == 60: continue #special case, should be skipped

    image_path = folder_path+f"/total_matrix_tangent {i}.png"
    img = cv2.imread(image_path)
    input.append(img.reshape(-1))
print("Loaded all",i,"images")
# change into numpy matrix
all_image = np.stack(input,axis=0)
# trans to 0-1 format float32!
all_image = (all_image.astype(np.float64))

### shape: #_of_imag x image_RGB_pixel_num (50331648 for normal case)
# print(all_image)
# print(all_image.shape)

# PCA, keeps 20 features
pca=PCA(n_components=20)
pca.fit_transform(all_image)
print("finished PCA")

result=pca.components_
print("PCA mean:",pca.mean_)

result=result.reshape(-1,4096,4096,3)
# result shape: #_of_componets * 4096 * 4096 * 3
# print(result.shape)

dst=result/np.linalg.norm(result,axis=(3),keepdims=True)
saving_path = "./principle64"
for i in range(20):
    reconImage=(dst)[i]
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(saving_path,("p"+str(i)+".png")),reconImage)
print("Saved",i+1,"principle imgs")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pca.components_` is not a list of transformed inputs - it is the *number* of principle components that will be retained, in your case, 20.

To get the reduced-dimensionality images, you need to use the `transform` or `fit_transform` methods:

```
# PCA, keeps 20 features
pca = PCA(n_components=20)

# Transform all_image
result = pca.fit_transform(all_image)
# result shape: num_of_images, 20
```

Note that the transformation will reduce the number of dimensions from 4096*4096*3 to 20, so the subsequent `reshape` operations do not make sense and will not work.

If you wish to attempt to reconstruct the original images using the retained information, you can call `inverse_transform`, ie

```
reconImages = pca.inverse_transform(result)
# reconImages shape: num_of_images, 4096 * 4096 * 3

reconImages = reconImages.reshape(-1, 4096, 4096, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks lot! Your answer solved the question! I made some mistakes when reading sklearn's document.